# Python convert GeoDataFrame to shapefile using ogr2ogr, unable to open error

Tags: python, ogr2ogr, geodataframe

I have a GeoDataFrame that I am trying to save as a shapefile using `ogr2ogr`. Based on the Q&A for [Use GeoDataFrame as a osgeo.ogr DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206195/use-geodataframe-as-a-osgeo-ogr-datasource) and [Using geopandas GeoDataFrame in gdal.Grid for spatial interpolation viz IDW, nearest neighbour etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396995/using-geopandas-geodataframe-in-gdal-grid-for-spatial-interpolation-viz-idw-nea), I am trying the following, but I keep getting the `FAILURE: Unable to open datasource` temp1' with the following drivers.` error

Working in Jupyter Notebook. Python 3.7, GDAL 3.3.1

I want to achieve this with GDAL, rather than GeoPandas/Fiona

```
### Import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

### Make geodataframe
pname = ['Project1'] * 5
id1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lat = [36.42, 36.4, 36.32, 36.28, 36.08]
long = [-118.11, -118.12, -118.07, -117.95, -117.95]
cat = ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']
id2 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(pname, id1, lat, long, cat, id2)), 
                  columns =['pname', 'id1', 'lat', 'long', 'cat', 'id2']) 
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
p = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['long'], df['lat']))
p = p.set_crs(epsg=4326)

### Try 1 (receive error)
temp1 = ogr.Open(p.to_json())

! ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" temp1.shp temp1

### Try 2 (receive error)
temp1 = gdal.OpenEx(p.to_json(), gdal.OF_VECTOR)

! ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" temp1.shp temp1
```

Comment: FWIW, `! ogrinfo temp1` also returns the same failure to open error

Comment: Why don't you use `p.to_file('tmp/test.shp')` to save GeoDataFrame as shapefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ogr2ogr- GDAL documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)

> ogr2ogr can be used to convert simple features data between file formats. It can also perform various operations during the process, such as spatial or attribute selection, reducing the set of attributes, setting the output coordinate system or even reprojecting the features during translation.

The problem here is that `temp1` is not a file

```
temp1 = gdal.OpenEx(p.to_json())
print(temp1.GetDriver().ShortName)
GeoJSON

! ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" temp1.shp temp1
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `temp1' with the following drivers.
...
-> GeoJSON
...
```

But this work

```
p.to_file("p.geojson", driver='GeoJSON') 
! ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" temp1.shp p.geojson
```

But if you want to use ogr, why not do everything with the python version of ogr ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to gdal & ogr, what do you mean by "do everything with python?" Can you show a simple code example?